# How to filter range and return only specific columns?

Tags: google-sheets, import, sorting, google-sheets-query

This is what I have tried just yet:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(Recherche!A4:O1002), "select Col1, Col15, Col2, Col3, Col4")
```

based on this format

```
=QUERY(FILTER(B:D,D:D>=2),"select Col2, Col1")
```

What I get is the following error:

> Error Can query string to parse for Parameter 2 function QUERY:
>   NO_COLUMN: Col15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
=QUERY(Recherche!A4:O1002, "select A, O, B, C, D")
```